# Is it possible to partially de-allocate memory from the middle of some object and "split" it?

Tags: c++, memory, split, memory-management, partial-specialization

For example I have an array of 200 integers. What I want to do is convert it to two arrays of 80 integers, removing the 40 integers in between. The goal of course is to use the existing memory block without allocating two new arrays of length 80 integers and copying from the first array, what I want is to cut the initial array from 80 to 120 and treat what is left as two separate arrays.

Move semantics uses a similar low level approach to avoid unnecessary copy of rvalues, so my question is if there is a low level approach to achieve a similar effect but assign the already existing data to multiple objects.

For example assigning pointers to the raw memory addresses of where the cuts are and the new elements begin, forcing them to act as arrays which use the same data, already allocated and filled in by the initial array?

Naturally, I could also delete the initial array and get its address and use that to assign its memory area to a new element, but **is it possible to tell C++ on which exact address to allocate a new object**? And also, **is there a way to guarantee the data of the initial array wont be corrupted in between its deletion and the reallocation of that same memory area to a new object**?

Such an approach is absent from any of the books on c++ I've read, but I get the feeling there might very well be some low level trickery to achieve the desired result.

Comment: You might be looking for [placement new](http://stackoverflow.com/a/222578/440558)?

Comment: For integers (and other fundamental types) there's no need to construct anything, and neither is there anything worth "moving". Also, do you mean "200"?

Comment: yeah sorry, a typo, that 100 was supposed to be 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using [placement-new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10). However, there is no way to guarantee that the content of a memory-location will not be changed between delete and a reallocation. Anyway, placement-new only enables you to construct an object in memory **that you already own**. So you'd have to allocate a pool of memory and then do your own memory management inside that pool.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that pretty much answers it all. Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) but it's generally not a good idea to go this low-level, unless you are really constrained.

Using it is a good idea when:

- You implement a memory pool
- You need to write to a precise memory location because the platform requires that (for example, memory mapped I/O on some embedded device).

Disadvantages of using it:

- You need to make sure that the allocated memory is large enough to hold the object.
- You need to explicitly call the destructor when the object is not needed anymore.

> is there a way to guarantee the data of the initial array wont be corrupted in between its deletion and the reallocation of that same memory area to a new object

No, that's up to the OS. It might be possible with a platform-specific API if it exists.

Comment: Replacing the new[] operator doesn't solve anything, unless you write a whole new memory management system that can change one block into two independent blocks. A whole lot of work!

Answer (score 2):

What I'd simply do is pass pointers to the relevant slices:

```
void i_need_80(int arr[80]);  // same as "int*"

std::array<int, 200> the_array;

i_need_80(the_array);
i_need_80(the_array + 120);
```

In place of `std::array<int, 200>` you can also have a dynamic `std::vector<int> v`, in which case you'd say `v.data()` and `v.data() + 120`.

Don't use `new`.

Comment: That's the way I would go as well unless there is an overarching reason to have them separated in memory. Keep it simple, stupid... you can also do this with "raw" arrays.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see so far why the OP would need anything more elaborate. Note that `std::array` *is* essentially a raw array, and you should never need to use actual raw arrays in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is call realloc() to resize (and possibly move) a block allocated with malloc() of realloc(). If the block was allocated using new[], even that isn't possible. The things you want require a rewrite (re-invention) of the memory management functions malloc(), free() and realloc().